# how to store data into database using text-area

Tags: asp.net

How to store data in the database.
it will show the following exception

Additional information: Procedure or function 'spUploadImage' expects parameter '@detail', which was not supplied.

Following is the Movies.aspx file contents :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var maxAmount = 250;
            function textCounter(textField, showCountField) {
                if (textField.value.length > maxAmount) {
                    textField.value = textField.value.substring(0, maxAmount);
                } else {
                    showCountField.value = maxAmount - textField.value.length;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <center>
                <asp:Label ID="label3" Text="Name of Movie: " runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br /><br />

                <asp:Label ID="label4" Text="Details of Movie: " runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
                <textarea id="txtCommentBox" name="txtCommentBox" rows="6" style="width:340px;" onKeyDown="textCounter(this.form.txtCommentBox,this.form.countDisplay);" onKeyUp="textCounter(this.form.txtCommentBox,this.form.countDisplay);"></textarea>
                <br />
                <input readonly type="text" name="countDisplay" size="3" maxlength="3" value="250"> Characters Remaining
           <br />

                    <br />
                <asp:Label ID="label2" Text="Select Image of Movie: " runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />

        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server">View Uploaded Image</asp:HyperLink>
 </center>

        </body>
    </html>
</asp:Content>
```

Following is the Movies.aspx.cs file contents :

```
   public partial class Movies : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        Label1.Visible = false;
        HyperLink1.Visible = false;
    }
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string txt = TextBox1.Text;
    string text = Request.Form["txtCommentBox_1"];
    HttpPostedFile postedFile= FileUpload1.PostedFile;
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
    string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
    int fileSize = postedFile.ContentLength;

    if(fileExtension.ToLower()==".jpg" || fileExtension.ToLower()==".png" || fileExtension.ToLower()==".bmp" || fileExtension.ToLower()==".gif")
    {
        Stream stream= postedFile.InputStream;
        BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(stream);
        byte[] bytes = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spUploadImage",con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter paramName = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@Name",
                Value = fileName
            };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramName);

            SqlParameter paramSize = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@Size",
                Value = fileSize
            };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramSize);

            SqlParameter parammName = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@mName",
                Value = txt
            };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parammName);



            SqlParameter paramImageData = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@ImageData",
                Value = bytes
            };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramImageData);

            SqlParameter paramdetail = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@detail",
                Value = text
            };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramdetail);

            SqlParameter paramNewId = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@NewId",
                Value = -1,
                Direction=ParameterDirection.Output
            };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramNewId);


            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            Label1.Visible = true;
            Label1.Text = "Upload Successful";
            Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            HyperLink1.Visible = true;
            HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "~/Moviesimg.aspx?Id="+cmd.Parameters["@NewId"].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Visible = true;
        Label1.Text = "Only Images (.jpg, .png, .gif and .bmp) can be uploaded...";
        Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        HyperLink1.Visible = false;
    }
}

}
```

and the stored procedure is as follows :

```
  create proc spUploadImage

    @Name nvarchar(255),
    @Size int,
    @ImageData varbinary(max),
    @mName nvarchar(50),
    @detail nvarchar(300),
    @NewId int output
  as
    Begin
      Insert into tblImages 
      values(@Name,@Size,@mName,@detail,@ImageData)
      select @NewId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    End
```

But I want to get a text from the text area and to store in the database.
but it raises an exception...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135374/additional-information-procedure-or-function-spuploadimage-expects-parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a form tag. Use an ASP control instead of a plain HTML control - all the other controls are ASP so be consistent.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <asp:TextBox id="txtImagename1" TextMode="multiline" Columns="50"   
                Rows="1" runat="server" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string text = Server.HtmlEncode(txtImagename1.Text);
    ...
}
```

The Request.Form collection cannot be used if your form is over 100 KB:

[msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: when i use this it will shows an exception cannot convert string to int

Comment: Use the debugger and see what's coming in from the textbox. An integer in a textbox should automatically be converted to a string as in "1".

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting `runat="server"` to any control, in that case the control must be placed inside a form tag with `runat="server"` like following

```
<html>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <center>
            <textarea id="txtImagename1" name="txtImagename1" runat="server" rows="1" cols="50">
             </textarea>
                    <br />
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server">View Uploaded Image</asp:HyperLink>
 </center>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

To access this on server side you can simply use the the `InnerText` property of the `TextArea` as following.

```
txtImagename1.InnerText
```

If you want you can also access it using `Form` object also as following.

```
Request.Form["txtImagename1"]
```

For this the control can be simple `TextArea` without `runat` attribute.

Comment: His HTML code is inside `asp:Content`, which mean there is `Form` in his master page .

Comment: Aria, he is not using a master page. If he was, the html and body tags would also be in his master.

Comment: i am using a master page bro

Comment: Then you're not using it correctly - check the documentation. The out html elements should be in the master page.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx